# Categories and links below

Tags: site-template, categories, links

How can I make a site, where I can choose between different categories, and below these add links such as a power point-file and pdf. Which template is best to use? people will not contribute add stuff etc. they will mostly look at informations.

example: categories --> culture. links below this image --> powerpoint and pdf file

2. categori/picture economy. links below this image --> powerpoint and pdf

Hope that the question is understandable

Comment: Think a enterprise-wikipage might be the best solution am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Summary Links web part. You can add links under group headers:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-and-configure-a-Summary-Link-Web-Part-or-a-Summary-Link-field-control-00d8ac9c-b7a6-43ee-90ed-e7db181e61a9#bm1